How remove entire rows in R based upon a set factor?
I am trying to remove 5 rows from my data set for those that have are defined as 'Underweight' under the column WeightStatus. I am not winning. The Data is called ANC.
I have tried the following
df_filtered <- ANC[!grepl("Underweight", ANC)]

And while this generates the df_filtered it does not remove the underweight rows. Any suggestions? Thank you

df_filtered <- ANC[!grepl("Underweight", ANC$WeightStatus) , ]  or df_filtered <- subset(ANC, !grepl("Underweight", WeightStatus))
